# How can I get confirmation of new security problem in struts2?

Tags: web-application, java, zero-day

I just read about this new [struts2 security problem](http://www.pwntester.com/blog/2014/04/24/struts2-0day-in-the-wild/). I want to tell our developers to patch it, but I wish for some more sources first.  The only source he cites is in another language.  I guess I could spend the better part of the day testing it, but if I could get confirmation from other sources, it would be better.  The blog author claims to have discussed it with the Struts security team.  How can I get confirmation from them that this is indeed a concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have since been updates from the Apache Struts Team:

http://struts.apache.org/announce.html#a20140424